# sparse matrix values as indexes to another matrix

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-engine

`S` - `N`x`N` sparse matrix.
`A` - `M`x1 vector.

The non zero values of `S` are the indexes of `A`.
I want to calculate a vector `x` such that in the `i`'th entry of `x`:
for each non zero value `j` in the `i`'th row of `S` , take `A[j]` and calculate the sum of all this `j`'s and put it in the `i`'th entry of `x`.

in pseudo it should look like this:

```
  for i = 1:N
     for j = 1:N
        if( s[i][j] != 0)
           x[i] += s[ A[i,j] ]
```

how can i do it in **matlab** in the most **efficient** way?

Comment: may be there should be another increment? like x[i] += A[s[i][j]]?

Answer (score 1):

Let's try using [`find`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html) and [`accumarray`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html):

```
[ii jj sij] = find( S );
x = accumarray( ii, A(sij), [1 size(S,1)] );
```

Comment: It think you need `x = accumarray( ii, A(jj), [size(S,1), 1] ).'`;

Comment: Hi, A is from dimension Mx1 and S is NxN, i mean that  A(jj) isn't correct I need to take A[S[i][j]]

Comment: this works fine or me:
      x = accumarray( ii, A(nonzeros(S)), [size(S,1), 1] ).'

thanks you guys

Answer (score 0):

This is just matrix multiplication:

```
x = (S~=0)*A(1:size(S,2));
```

Matlab does matrix multiplication efficiently with sparse matrices, so this should be pretty fast.

Comment: what if `numel(A)<size(S,2)`?

Comment: @Shai I've no idea. The problem is unspecified in that case. The OP should indicate what they want. In that case their code would also fail, as would yours (even with my correction).

Comment: but as i said:
S - NxN sparse matrix.
A - Mx1 vector.

when M is not necessarily equals to N

Comment: @user3175582 But M has to be greater than or equal to N, or else the problem is undefined

Answer (score 0):

This is actually like Shai's answer, but uses nonzeros(S) instead sij:

```
[ii jj] = find( S );
x = accumarray( ii, A(nonzeros(S)), [size(S,1), 1] ).'
```

Comment: This is essentially [Shai's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29671739/2586922). You should accept that answer (specially if Shai makes the correction) instead of posting your own